# ASPOSE Slides AMAZON Lambda python

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aspose-slides

I have some doubt about implementation aspose slides within amazon Lambda, I want to download file inside Amazon Lambda from Bucket, then I need convert this document to PDF Format using ASPOSE SLIDE Library but when I’ve executed the code, show the next message when invoke asposeslidescloud.SlidesApi(configuration) function:

“errorMessage”: “[Errno 38] Function not implemented”,
" File “/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py”, line 57, in init\n sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(

I don’t know how integrate this strategy between AWS Lambda and Aspose Slides using Python.
This code is given the below section:

````
configuration = asposeslidescloud.Configuration()
configuration.app_sid = os.environ[‘APP_SID’]
configuration.app_key = os.environ[‘APP_KEY’]
return asposeslidescloud.SlidesApi(configuration)```
````

Comment: Have you packed this external library and uploaded to lambda?

Comment: Yes, I've packed this external library and some lines using this Library works, but when invokes this function **asposeslidescloud.SlidesApi(configuration)** generating this error. I understand that Lambda doesn't uses multithreading but I need uses this asposes for this task.

Comment: @RogerGuzman we are investigating the issue that you also posted in aspose.cloud forum(https://forum.aspose.cloud/t/aspose-slides-amazon-lambda/6335) and will share our findings soon.